# "off of" in the sense of "before"

Tags: difference, british-english

I oftentimes watch British youtubers and observe that they use "off of" in the sense of "before". this is something I've never come across in American English or any dialect of American English.

for instance: "off of recording the video I ran into some technical problems"

Can you elaborate on it? It's not the kind of thing I'm familiar with since I consume mostly American products.

Comment: I would understand that to mean _in the process of recording the video_ rather than _before_.

Comment: Such a usage is deeply casual, informal, and definitely not standard English. This is common on Youtube etc videos.

Answer (score 1):

"Off of" in casual BrE usage means "from" not "before".
'That bloke off of the telly' = 'That man from the TV show'.

It's terrible usage, but became a popular meme when a Radio 1* DJ picked up on it & used it excessively in the 90s.

*Biggest radio station in the UK at the time, BBC.

Frankly, as a Brit, "off of recording the video" means absolutely nothing to me. I would definitely need more context before I could even guess at what they meant by it.

Answer (score -1):

I just want to give example about this question;

"We would be reaching there before sunset" this sentence is 100% correct.

"We would be reaching there off sunset" this sentence is not okay in my opinion.

If I am wrong, please correct my mistakes.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you are not sure about that, please don't write an answer, as incorrect information only confuses people.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/136676)